# .msi file not found during VS2015 install

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

When install progress is started, it suddenly claims the *msi* package for *Visual C++ 2015 x64 minimum runtime* is not found, which should be located at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A1C31BA5-5438-3A07-9EEE-A5FB2D0FDE36}v14.0.23506\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi
```

I have tried many times, and it is always missing this same *msi* file.

This is really suprising for me: the installer of Visual Studio 2015 is web based, so all packages are downloaded in-time and are managed by the installer itself, but why this one specific package is always missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by packages that are installed but msi files missed in system storage. After some works, I found a way to uninstall nonexisting msi packages:

1. install some 3rd-party uninstaller or package manager;
2. use their's scan utility to remove registration entries.

After that, the system will not still consider the msi package being in installed state, and the VS installer will not raise an error. However, in my system, many msi files are affected, so it is still a tedious work.

Comment: Any idea why "many msi files" are affected? Removing registration entries for Windows Installer can cause all kinds of side effects, including corrupting the whole MSI database. Perhaps you mean "uninstall" rather than "remove registration entries"?